# How to get the selected size of the file using faker in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created a factory in my project file using [fzaninotto/faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#fakerproviderfile) like this :

```
      'icon' => $faker->file($sourceDir='/home/gujarat/fakerFile/images', $targetDir='./public/iconLibrary', false),
      'title' => $faker->name,
      'date' => $faker->numberBetween($min = 1900, $max = 2016),
      'size' => $faker->randomFloat($nbMaxDecimals = 10.0, $min = 2.0, $max = 10.0),
      'file_type' => 'video/mp4',
      'download_url' => $faker->file($sourceDir='/home/gujarat/fakerFile/video', $targetDir='./public/videoLibrary', false),
      'category_id' => $randomCategory->id,
```

I need to get the size of the selected file from $faker->file() as you can see in my field `download_url` in MB or KB, and the file extension is **.mp4** is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the path of the file, and use `filesize()` from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) to determine the size of the file. 
I manage to do this in my factory class like this :

```
$factory->defineAs(App\Library::class, 'library_video', function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
  $categories = Category::all();
  $randomCategory = $categories->random();

  $randomFile = $faker->file($sourceDir='/home/gujarat/fakerFile/video', $targetDir='./public/videoLibrary', false);
  $size = filesize("./public/videoLibrary/".$randomFile);


  return [
      'icon' => $faker->file($sourceDir='/home/gujarat/fakerFile/images', $targetDir='./public/iconLibrary', false),
      'title' => $faker->name,
      'date' => $faker->numberBetween($min = 1900, $max = 2016),
      'download_url' => $randomFile,
      'size' => $size,
      'file_type' => 'video/mp4',
      'category_id' => $randomCategory->id,
  ];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.html) which extends symfony's [UploadedFile](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html) class

```
$path = $faker->file($sourceDir='/home/gujarat/fakerFile/video', $targetDir='./public/videoLibrary', false);
$uploadedFile = new Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile($path, 'randomName');
$uploadedFile->getClientSize();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use php function [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

`list($width, $height) = getimagesize("dir/image.jpg");`